# SQL SELECT HH:MM - HH:MM

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to write an SQL query that will return the current time as follows:

HH:MM - HH:MM (+1)

E.g. if the time is 14:00 it would return 14:00 - 15:00

I have managed to get as far as follows:

```
SELECT TOP (30) 
    DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, QUEUE_TIME.QueueDate), 0) AS 'DateAdded',
    CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(HH, QUEUE_TIME.QueueDate), 108) AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' - ' + 
    CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(HH, QUEUE_TIME.QueueDate), 108) + 1 AS VARCHAR(2)) AS Interval, 
    QUEUE_TYPE.Name, QUEUE_TIME.QueueTypeId, 
    MAX(QUEUE_TIME.QueuedTimeInSec / 60) AS 'WaitingTimeInSec', 
    CAST(ROUND(AVG(QUEUE_TIME.FlowRateWhenJoinedPerMin), 1) AS numeric(36, 2)) AS AvgFlowRate
FROM
    QUEUE_TIME 
INNER JOIN
    QUEUE_TYPE ON QUEUE_TIME.QueueTypeId = QUEUE_TYPE.Id
WHERE
    (QUEUE_TIME.QueueDate >= '11/07/2014 00:00') 
    AND (QUEUE_TIME.IsFreeFlowing = '0') 
    AND (QUEUE_TIME.QueueTypeId = '3')
GROUP BY 
    DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, QUEUE_TIME.QueueDate), 0), 
    DATEPART(HOUR, QUEUE_TIME.QueueDate), QUEUE_TYPE.Name, QUEUE_TIME.QueueTypeId
ORDER BY 
    'DateAdded'
```

This will return as follows, e.g. if it is 8am it will return 8-9. But i need it to be in the format 08:00 - 09:00.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

I am using SQL Server 2008.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is an example, you can replace `@now` variable with column name:

```
declare @now datetime = getdate()

select convert(varchar(5), @now, 114) + ' - ' + 
       convert(varchar(5), dateadd(hour, 1, @now), 114) yourColumn
```

**[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/36622)**

Comment: (if you have an older version of SQL Server, may have to move that "= getdate()" to a second line)

Comment: @MikeM yes, assigning a default value in the same line works in sql server versions on and after 2008.

Comment: Nice answer...  have not used 114 before :)

Answer (score 2):

Try with [`FORMAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql) for SQL Server 2012+:

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'HH:mm') + '-' + FORMAT(DATEADD(HH, 1, GETDATE()), 'HH:mm')
```

Comment: ( if in SQL Server 2012 or 2014 ) ...  (but OP said 2008)

Comment: Ah yes. It's good to read to the bottom of a post. Thanks for the correction @MikeM.